# us WHERE statement and ARRAY for AthenaQuery

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have an SQL query like this (written for PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.company_id = ANY(ARRAY[945387, 969109, 1460013, 1460044]) AND
 users.profession_id = ANY(ARRAY[2738, 6388]) 
GROUP BY users.company_id
```

but I can't run it like this for AthenaQuery (getting `SYNTAX_ERROR: Function any not registered`). 
How can I convert it?

Comment: The `GROUP BY users.company_id` makes no sense (together with `select *` and no aggregates).  What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Actually it was just a simplification of the whole query to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the array operator to a standard `IN` condition.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.company_id IN (945387, 969109, 1460013, 1460044) 
  AND users.profession_id IN (2738, 6388)
GROUP BY users.company_id
```